# Spring: @RequestBody not deserializing serialized JSON field declared using alternate name

Tags: java, json, spring, gson, json-deserialization

I have one input request DTO for a Patch call

```
@Data
public class RequestDTO {
  String name;
  @SerializedName(value= "requestNumber", alternate = {"requestNo"})
  String requestNumber;
}
```

My Controller method looks something like:

```
@PatchMapping("/path")
public ResponseEntity<ResponseDTO> updateSomething(@RequestBody @Valid RequestDTO requestDTO) {
  //some code here
  if(requestDTO.getRequestNumber == null) {
    log.error("Deserialization failure");
  }
  //return something
}
```

When I try to deserialize request DTO using Gson, I am able to do it with both the field names, `requestNumber` and `requestNo`

Example:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String input = "{"name": "abc", "requestNumber": "1"};
RequestDTO requestDTO = gson.fromJson(input, RequestDTO.class);
Assert.assertNotNull(requestDTO.getRequestNumber)     //Test passed
```

And

```
String input = "{"name": "abc", "requestNo": "1"};
RequestDTO requestDTO = gson.fromJson(input, RequestDTO.class);
Assert.assertNotNull(requestDTO.getRequestNumber)     //Test passed
```

Irrespective of field name is requestNumber of requestNo in input JSON, it is deserialized properly.

But whenever I pass a request DTO of the form `{"name": "abc", "requestNo": "1"}` to my patch call, on deserialization, value of `requestNumber` field in the deserialized DTO always turns out to be `null`. Deserialized DTO looks like:

```
{
  "name": "abc",
  "requestNumber": null
}
```

It works well when input field name is `requestNumber`. What is the reason behind this?

What is best way to deserialize the value in requestBody with both field names?

I cannot stick to only one field name because my actual DTO (this is dummy one) is used by multiple systems and it is not possible to have only either field name.

Comment: Are sure that GSon is used as JSON deserializer by your Spring application. By default Spring use a Jackson ObjectMapper.

Comment: Thanks for the lead. I was not aware of the fact that Spring uses Jackson ObjectMapper. When I used @JsonAlias("requestNo") annotation for the field, I am able to deserialize with both the field names.

Answer (score 0):

Spring uses Jackson Object Mapper for deserializing JSON objects. Since @SerializedName annotation belongs to Gson and not to Jackson, it will not take the alternate value. Use @JsonAlias from Jackson for alternate field names.

```
@JsonAlias("requestNo")
String requestNumber;
```

This will help in deserializing values declared using both field names.